# datagridview cell value changed

Tags: c#

i faced problem with my datagridview that when user change the value of one cell .. the column 'save' the is link cell change the value to save .. this is my code :

```
private void childrenDgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        childrenDgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["save"].Value = "save";
        DataGridViewLinkCell linkcell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
        childrenDgv[ "save" , e.RowIndex] = linkcell;


    }
```

but the problem that when user change the value of any cell in datagridview the program throw this error : is read only 'save' system.data.readonlyexception : column at system.data.datarow.set_item(data_column column , object value ) ... etc ..

Comment: I might be wrong, but try `linkcell = childDgv[etc.];`. This sets the value of `'save'` into the `linkcell`. The way you have it sets the reverse.

Comment: the problem is i tried the same code on another datagridview and every thing go good .. there is no error !!

Comment: hmm... maybe just try and double check all of your names, and all the read-only properties on your datagridview?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense.  First you set the Value of a cell and then you replace that whole cell with a new one.  Why are you creating that new cell at all?

Comment: it 's not hard just check the code i poste .. when i comment this event .. and run the program and change cell value .. every thing good .. and no errors !!

Comment: maybe my code is not sense .. but i tried it on another datagridview and is is working fine

Comment: To me it seems that if the same code works on another table, then the issue would have to be something to do with the table that is causing the error. For example something to do with the `ReadOnly` property perhaps?

Comment: ok . if the problem with read only property .. the exception must thrown with the event or without the event .. but when i remove cell value changed event .. and change the value of cell .. there is no exception !!